# Dynamically change column names based on inputs

Tags: r, function, dataframe, do.call, qdap

I am trying to dynamically name the output of a data frame based upon the inputs.

```
get.max2 <- function(data = NULL, column)
{
  #require(qdap)
  col <- eval(substitute(column), data)
  max <- max(eval(substitute(column), data))
  name <- lookup(col, max, rownames(data))
  name <- name[!is.na(name)]
  #title <- do.call('paste', list(paste(match.call()[1])))
  df <- data.frame(name = name, title = max(col))
  print(df)
}
```

Currently, the output looks like this:

```
get.max2(mtcars, mpg)

      name title
Volvo 142E  33.9
```

But, I want it to look like this:

```
get.max2(mtcars, mpg)

      name  mpg
Volvo 142E 33.9
```

I think the answer has something to do with match.call/do.call, but my knowledge is fuzzy at best when using these functions.  Anyone know if this possible?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're `title=..` statement is almsot there.

you want to use instead:

```
 title = paste(match.call()[-(1:2)], collapse=" ")   
 # the collapse argument is optional, it's not clear
 #    how you would like to handle multiple arguments
```

---

Notice the two main differences from what you had:

1. using `[-(1:2)]` instead of `[1]`.   The element from `match.call()` is the function name, which you do not want.  Alternatively, you can use `match.call()[3]` if you want just the second argument.
2. In this situation, there is no need for `do.call(.)`.  `paste` works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for something like `?deparse` and `?substitute`.

```
variableName <- function(x) {
  return(deparse(substitute(x)))
}

variableName(title)
# [1] "title"

variableName(mpg)
# [1] "mpg"
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyone's help!  Another workaround that I discovered was to rename the data frame after processing.

```
get.max2 <- function(data = NULL, column)
{
  #require(qdap)
  #require(gdata)
  col <- eval(substitute(column), data)
  max <- max(eval(substitute(column), data))
  name <- lookup(col, max, rownames(data))
  name <- name[!is.na(name)]
  df <- data.frame(name = name, title = max(col))
  title2 <- do.call('paste', list(paste(match.call()[3])))
  df <- rename.vars(df, 'title', title2, info = F)
  return(df)
}
```

Which returns:

```
get.max2(mtcars, mpg)

      name  mpg
Volvo 142E 33.9
```